# Android webview on orientation screen

Tags: android, android-webview

In Android webview I want to change URL when screen is orientation change.
Here is code from this post ([landscape view and portrait view of webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994140/landscape-view-and-portrait-view-of-webview-in-android?rq=1)) I tried so far but did't work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    {

    }
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.HRTimestation.app" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you just missed one thing. Add configuration data in the manifest file for your activity.`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Like following

```
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```