# How do I let my webview go landscape in android

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to learn how to use the webview, I just noticed that the webview does not work in landscape mode, i tried a lot of ways but none of them work, how do i go about doing that?
(I am using Java)

I tried this:
[landscape view and portrait view of webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19994140/10952503)

My code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView MainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MainWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = MainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        MainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        WebView MainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MainWebView);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            MainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            MainWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is working for me I used this code

  ```
    WebView webView =findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.in/");
  ```

Comment: doesnt work i get this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/507857234034819072/947441667772940359/Screenshot_20220227-133409_Trebuchet.png EDIT: i fixed it, i had to set the webview to fill parent

Comment: what device you are using for testing

Comment: i fixed it i forgot to change its size, thanks for the help

Comment: ok, what device were you using

Comment: samsing galaxy S5 android 11 (lineage 18.1)